# Passing hadoop configuration to Nutch crawl command

Tags: hadoop, nutch

I want to be able to specify the number of mappers, reducers and job queue while running Apache Nutch crawl command in distributed mode. Here is what I have tried, but is not working:

```
runtime/deploy/bin/crawl -D mapreduce.map.memory.mb=4000 -D mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=2000 -D mapred.job.queue.name=some-queue -i -D solr.server.url=http://http://my-solr-server:8983/solr/my-collection -s /user/me/seed /user/me/crawl-dir 1
```

How do I pass the hadoop params to the command?

Comment: delete the space between the -D and the class 
ex: `-Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=4000`

Comment: @Quent it does not work with the nutch crawl command with that change. I am trying it with nutch 1.14.

Comment: for me this works in 1.15 and 1.14 too
`runtime/deploy/bin/crawl -D "mapreduce.map.memory.mb=4000" -D "mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=2000" -D "mapred.job.queue.name=some-queue" -i -D "solr.server.url=http://http://my-solr-server:8983/solr/my-collection" -s /user/me/seed /user/me/crawl-dir 1`

In 1.15 -Dsolr.server.url not mandatory if you have configured index-writers.xml